# Make sure jQuery is loaded before using package

Tags: jquery, meteor

Im trying to implement a package that uses jQuery. Upon running `meteor` i get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` error. If I click a button which calls a function in this new package, i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).turnBox is not a function`. How can I make sure jQuery is loaded before using the package?

EDIT: Fixed, see comments.

Comment: What does your `package.js` look like? You may have forgotten to `api.use` jQuery.

Comment: Yup, just added `api.use('jquery');` and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, don't forget to `api.use` in your package.js file:

```
api.use('jquery');
```